# Sharing a video link on facebook ios

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to share a link of a video that I uploaded in my website host. But the post doesn't show my video and a thumbnail image. I want my post to look like this image bellow:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcbTG.png

is there anyway to post my video like that?

I'm using facebook SDK 3.1.1, ARC, Cocos2d 2.0, IOS 5.1;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you supply the correct Open Graph Tags as per https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/#audiovideo your video can embed in the News Feed post.

To accomplish the actual Sharing, you should use the [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) which is customizable and will work on desktop and mobile devices.

Comment: I have updated my original answer to add information about that.